# How to scroll the terminal emulator window in smaller steps using the keyboard?

Tags: terminal, scrolling, xterm

How could I scroll up and down the bash shell window (without the mouse or scroll bars, just using the keyboard)?

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> acts like page up and page down.

**But how could one scroll just one line up or down?** 
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate (but on [unix.se], and newer, contains more information): [urxvt-scroll-just-one-line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44756) ; [keybinding-in-xterm-to-shift-one-line-up-using-shiftup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138501) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Gnome terminal](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/gnome-terminal-usage.html.en#gnome-terminal-contents) (and others) uses <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to scroll one row.
But <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> should work in most other terminal emulators (like `xterm` or `urxvt` if  not intercepted by windows managers or stuff.

Comment: Indeed, **Left Ctrl** + **Left/Right Shift** + **Up/Down** does the trick! (It doesn't work for me with **Right Ctrl**.)

Comment: @MishaMoroshko Probably because VirtualBox.

Answer (score 32):

If using [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/), you can see all shortcuts in Preferences Panel.

<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> Move one line up in scrollback buffer

<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> Move one line down in scrollback buffer

---

You can also add your own shortcuts. I regularly use these 2 for example:

<kbd>⇪</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> Move one page up in scrollback buffer

<kbd>⇪</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> Move one page down in scrollback buffer

---

And that's how  it looks like:

[image]

Comment: the keys you use for scrolling a page up in the scrollback buffer are now default for "scrolling back to the previous command". Add that to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this myself on Ubuntu 12.10. Scrolling back linewise works using ctrl+shift (both, for left and right buttons) and up and down keys of the keypad with numlock activated (meaning when you don't use a modifier key, numbers will be typed)! It does not work for the normal up and down keys or keypad keys with numlock deactivated.